# JButton text with different font family in different words

Tags: java, html, swing, fonts

I am trying to achieve a button with its text having two different font family.

I think, it can be achieved using HTML, as said on this page.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html

I've tried the following code, but it's not working.

```
JButton button = new JButton("<html>Hello <font family=Serif>World</font></html>");
```

May be the `font` tag attribute `family` is wrong!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> May be the font tag attribute family is wrong!

It is indeed, the right tag should be:

```
<font face="Serif"></font>
```

Take a look to [HTML font tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp). So in your case:

```
JButton button = new JButton("<html>Hello <font face=\"Serif\">World</font></html>");
```

#### Picture

[image]

Comment: Or more simple: `<font face=Serif>World</font>`.